# Differentiating between files and directories on linux in C

Tags: c, linux, directory, stat, readdir

I have a function that takes in an argument which is a file path. That path is then used in conjunction with the `readdir` function and `stat` function to print out all of the files and directories in a directory. The issue I have is when I try to sort the files and directories, they are all viewed as directories. I have looked at similar examples on here and I believe the issue is the way I have stat formatted. I just don't understand how stat works and I have even looked at the manual pages but they are not making a lot of sense.

Here is my code:

```
void scan(const char *dir) {
    DIR *directory;
    struct dirent *file;
    struct stat info;

    directory = opendir(dir);

    if (directory == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open directory: %s\n", dir);
        return;
    }
    while ((file = readdir(directory)) != NULL) {
        if (file->d_name[0] == '.') {
            // then hidden file, so leave hidden
            continue;
        }
        
        if (stat(dir, &info) == -1) {
            printf("can't find %s\n", file->d_name);
            perror("ERROR");
        }

        // determine if file or directory
        if (S_ISREG(info.st_mode))
            printf("File: ");
        if (S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
            printf("Dir: ");

        // display the name of the file
        printf("%s\n", file->d_name);
    }
    closedir(directory);
}
```

Here is the output that I keep getting...

```
Dir: par_hash_table.c
Dir: BlackBoxTesting
Dir: Makefile
Dir: in3.txt
Dir: par_hash_table.o
Dir: in5.txt
Dir: par_hash_table
Dir: in4.txt
Dir: in6.txt
Dir: in1.txt
Dir: in2.txt
Dir: in8.txt
Dir: in7.txt
```

Here is the command I am using, I'm using Linux and the file path doesn't need to be this particular but I just wanted to show everything...

```
./par_hash_table 1 2 /home/dpb/Documents/CSE_420/P3
```

Any help figuring out how I can differentiate a txt file from a folder would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
    if(stat(dir, &info) == -1){
        printf("can't find %s\n", file->d_name);
        perror("ERROR");
       }
```

You are getting `stat` for the function parameter `dir` every time. You want to stat the file from the directory entry, instead. So you need to concatenate the dir and the file names, to get full path for `stat`.

---

Code to concat the parts:

```
char filepath[strlen(dir) + 1 + strlen(file->d_name) + 1];
snprintf(filepath, sizeof filepath, "%s/%s", dir, file->d_name);
if(stat(filepath, &info) == -1){
   ....
```

(A side note, incidentally this is one of the *very* few cases where I think using a VLA is fine. Just be careful if you convert this to a recursive function, make sure the VLA goes out of scope before the recursive call... Or just use `malloc` and `free` to be safe from stack overflow.)

---

Also, please run your code through auto-formater, which also can add the missing optional `{}`. It really is quite a good idea to use `{}` for every block, even if it is just one statement. Or, if you don't find a C auto-formatter, your editor should at least have auto-indentation, so add the `{}` yourself and then auto-indent the code.

Comment: stat is not part of the c standard library. what does that mean? baseline c does not have stat. this is the POSIX standard library youre suggesting here.

Comment: @muzzletov: the program uses the POSIX Standard functions. The OP documents the target is a linux system.

Comment: @chqrlie yes, thats why the title is wrong or misleading

Comment: @hyde: the function `fstatat()` is a good workaround to avoid the need for path concatenation.  It is available on linux since 2.6.16 and other recent Unices.

Comment: @chqrlie Great minds think alike. I was putting together a demonstration of `fstatat()` when you made that comment.

Comment: @hyde This worked but I'm not familiar with the format of stat, d_name, and snprintf so I'm looking up some stuff about it so it makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to concatenating the filename in the `dirent` structure onto the path so `stat()` will work is using [`fstatat()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) instead with a file descriptor for the directoryand the plain filename.

Also, on some filesystems, [`readdir()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) will fill in the `dirent` structure's `d_type` field with the type of the file, so if that's the case, you can get away without doing a stat at all.

Example (Also including some improvements to error reporting and handling; one issue with your code is continuing on and testing the stat structure even when the function fails):

```c
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void scan(const char *dir) {
    DIR *directory;
    struct dirent *file;

    directory = opendir(dir);

    if (directory == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open directory %s: %s\n", dir, strerror(errno));
      return;
    }
    int dfd = dirfd(directory); // directory's file descriptor

    while ((file = readdir(directory)) != NULL) {
      if (file->d_name[0] == '.') {
        // then hidden file, so leave hidden
        continue;
      }

      if (file->d_type == DT_UNKNOWN) {
        // Only stat the file if we don't already have the file type available
        struct stat info;
        if (fstatat(dfd, file->d_name, &info, 0) < 0) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Can't stat %s/%s: %s\n",
                  dir, file->d_name, strerror(errno));
          continue;
        }
        if (S_ISREG(info.st_mode)) {
          file->d_type = DT_REG;
        } else if (S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)) {
          file->d_type = DT_DIR;
        }
      }

      // determine if file or directory
      if (file->d_type == DT_REG)
        printf("File: ");
      else if (file->d_type == DT_DIR)
        printf("Dir: ");
      else
        printf("Other: ");

      // display the name of the file
      printf("%s\n", file->d_name);
    }

    closedir(directory);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s DIRECTORY\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  scan(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would use this way because it makes more sense to me, however the problem requires me to use stat().